# Implementing Probability Score for Threshold Based Classification Model

Tags: machine-learning, probability, predictive-models

I have a binary classification model that has properties min_loss and max_loss. Example: `min_loss=0.02` and `max_loss=0.5`. Part of the algorithm of the model is that it automatically creates a threshold value in between those ranges. Example: `threshold=0.08`. Given an unknown input, the model produces a loss value loss. The way the the model predicts is that if `loss > threshold` then `prediction = -1` else if `loss <= threshold` then `prediction=1`. Since the threshold is automatically computed, how might a function look like if I want it to produce probabilities similar to predict_proba of sklearn? Ideally, I want the predict_proba function to produce something like `[0.4, 0.6]`.